# Is a 16GB iPhone supposed to only have 11GBs available?

Tags: iphone

I have a iPhone 5S and it's reporting a capacity of 11.8GB. I would have thought that 16GB would mean 16GB?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can check on Apple's storage capacity guide [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201402), but in short may be caused by two factors:

1. The system reserves a portion of your storage for itself, system files, system partitions, buffer, metadata, etc. Regarding this, I am not entirely sure how much capacity this stuff uses, but you cannot delete it; iOS needs it to run.
2. When they say that the phone includes a 16GB flash drive, they mean 16000000000 bytes (decimal system), which is about 14,89 GB in binary system (1024*1024*1024=1GB). As the guide says:

> The way decimal and binary numeral systems measure a GB is what causes a 32 GB storage device to appear as approximately 28 GB when detailed by its operating system, even though the storage device still has 32 billion bytes (not 28 billion bytes), as reported.

Answer (score 2):

16 GB total is still 16 GB.  The amount used by the OS should take up space; therefore, the free space will be reduced.  My phone also shows 11.9 GB total on a 16 GB iPhone 5S with 9.0 GB available.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will take 11.8 GB out of 16 GB because every storage device has to be formatted before it can store data files and the formatting process uses some of the device's storage (the exact amount varies depending on the OS and filesystem in use, it gets quite technical). The storage capacity for iOS devices (like PCs and Macs also) is advertised as unformatted, some quantity of that number will be used by the formatting process and is thus unavailable to the user. This will be the smallest contributor to your "missing GBs" issue, but it will make a small difference to your iPhone.